Razor page not loading but no errors
I have a razor page that has several AJAX functions running to fetch data and update it.
The pages work fine locally and in SOME of the production instances.
But in a few instances, I get a console message (Chrome Console) saying there's been a 500 error. I've added logs everywhere and the app doesn't seem to fail (Besides if there was an error with the application per se, it would fail in ALL the instances).
The weid behavior I'm seeing in the instances that don't work is that (through logging) I've seen that normal instances call one time the OnGet method and then, all the subsequent calls are OnPostIndexPartial, however, the faulty instances called the OnGet mnethod TWICE, and thenm nothing happens.
I even addded a little bit of logic to ensure the call only happens once, and even though the message now appears only one time, the page still never loads (not OnGet even)
I'm stumped. I've been at it for hours now and cant seem to find why it never even renders the initial page (therefore not doing any of the subsecuent onPartialPosts)
If anyone has ever seen a behaviour like this and has some pointers/tipos to debug or find what's wrong with these instances, I'd be very grateful
Thank you in advance for your time
EDIT
This is the model (some code has been removed) - Single model handles petitions
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DTEmbarcado.Controllers;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using DTEmbarcado.DTOS;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace DTEmbarcado.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public bool initialPetitionDone = false;

        public IndexModel()
        {

        }

        public JsonResult OnPostHeartbeatPartial(string name)
        {
            GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog("OnPostHeartbeatPartial", DTLogger.INFO);
            Object json = null;
            try
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize("OK");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog($"OnPostHeartbeatPartial ERROR: {ex.Message} : {ex.StackTrace} : {ex.InnerException}", DTLogger.ERROR);
            }
            return new JsonResult(json);
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog("GET Index", DTLogger.INFO);
            try
            {
                if (!initialPetitionDone)
                {
                    initialPetitionDone = true;
                    
                    //SOME CODE
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog($"GET Index ERROR: {ex.Message} : {ex.StackTrace} : {ex.InnerException}", DTLogger.ERROR);
            }
        }

        public JsonResult OnPostIndexPartial(string visualizationOptions, string searchPorts, string searchVars)
        {
            GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog("ON POST INDEX PARTIAL", DTLogger.INFO);
            var json = "";
            try
            {
                //SOME CODE
                this.Data = result;
                json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(this.Data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog($"OnPostIndexPartial ERROR: {ex.Message} : {ex.StackTrace} : {ex.InnerException}", DTLogger.ERROR);
            }
            return new JsonResult(json);
        }
    }
}

This is the javascript executing in the cshtml (it's a lot of code):
@page
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model DTEmbarcado.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
}

<div id="body" class="col-12 border text-left p-3 mt-3 d-flex">
    <table id="valuesTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @try
            {
                @if (Model.Data != null)
                {
                    //Some code
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalConstants.logger.insertaLog($"Ha ocurrido un error cargando Model.Data: {ex.Message}\n {ex.InnerException} \n {ex.StackTrace}",DTLogger.ERROR);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts{

    @*GLOBALS*@
    <script>
        var sendRequest = true;
        var sendHeartbeat = false;
        function pop(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
        }

        function hide(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>

    @*HEARTBEAT*@
    <script>
        var refreshTime = 2000;
        const currentUrl = window.location.href;

        $(function () {
            setInterval(setHeartbeat, refreshTime);
            setHeartbeat();
        });

        function setHeartbeat(){
            if (sendHeartbeat){
                pop('popDiv');
                var xhr = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    timeout: 1000,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    url: '/?handler=HeartbeatPartial',
                    data: {
                        name: name
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-encoding': 'gzip'
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        hide('popDiv');
                        sendHeartbeat = false;
                        sendRequest = true;
                    },
                    error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
                        if (textstatus === "timeout") {
                            xhr.abort();
                        }
                        pop('popDiv');
                        sendRequest = false;
                        sendHeartbeat = true;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        //# sourceURL=heartbeatSource
    </script>

    @* REFRESH SCRIPT *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var refreshTime = 1000;
        var VOArray = [];

        $(function () {
            setInterval(loadTable, refreshTime);
            loadTable();
        });

        function loadTable() {
            //TIMEOUT
            var isDataReceived = false;
            //SOME CODE
            //FLAG SETTING
            if(sendRequest){
                hide('popDiv');
                //AJAX CALL
                var xhr = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    timeout: 3000,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        //console.log("Sending POST request");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    url: '/?handler=IndexPartial',
                    data: {
                        visualizationOptions: visualizationOptions,
                        searchPorts: searchPorts,
                        searchVars: searchVars
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-encoding':'gzip'
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        keys = []
                        isDataReceived = true;
                        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(Object.keys(jsonObject).length === 0){
                            $("#valuesTable tbody tr").remove();
                        }else{
                            $.each(jsonObject, function(index, variable){
                                keys.push(variable.name)
                                if(document.getElementById(variable.name)){
                                    document.getElementById(variable.name+"Value").innerText = variable.value;
                                    document.getElementById(variable.name+"LastUpdate").innerText = variable.lastUpdate;
                                }
                                else{
                                    addRow(variable)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        $('#valuesTable tr').each(function (index, tr) {
                            var name = tr.id
                            if (name !== "") {
                                if (!keys.includes(name)) {
                                    document.getElementById(tr.id).remove();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
                        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
                            xhr.abort();
                        }
                        else if (textstatus === "error"){
                            pop('popDiv');
                            sendRequest = false;
                            sendHeartbeat = true;
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    //# sourceURL=ChromeConsoleDebug
    </script>
}

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


You need to create a model and attach [FromBody] attribute to it to receive json data in request body,I've updated with more details in my answer


I've added logs everywhere and the app doesn't seem to fail

Just add a middleware before your other middlewares  :
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        app.logger.LogError(e.Message);
    }
    
});

remove the default Excpetion handler middleware:
- app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

Then any exception related with serverside codes  during the whole request would be recorded.If it log nothing,you could research other possible reasons and provide us more details

I've seen that normal instances call one time the OnGet method and
then, all the subsequent calls are OnPostIndexPartial

does OnGet handlder and OnPostIndexPartial in the same page model?could you show how you send the request?It seems that your post request hit the OnGet handler
public JsonResult OnPostIndexPartial(string visualizationOptions, string searchPorts, string searchVars){
.......
}

should be relpaced with
public class YourViewModel 

{
  public string visualizationOptions{get;set;}
public string searchPorts{get;set;}
public string searchVars{get;set;}
}



public JsonResult OnPostIndexPartial([FromBody] YourViewModel viewmodel){
    .......
    }


I've added the middleware and nothing's being logged. I've also added the model and cshtml to the question as requested
